# PAM2804 Lithium-ion single cell LED driver fails

Tags: led-driver

**UPDATE (2021-Jan-16) - All working as expected** - Project [link](https://oshwlab.com/jinantha/pam2804-led-driver-for-cree-xm-l) for anyone to build or do as they please.

[PAM2804](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/PAM2804.pdf), I've been trying to use this chip for a single Li-ion cell flashlight project, but it does not work for me. I've designed 2 PCBs so far, but both failed.

I'm driving a [Cree X-Lamp XML](https://www.cree.com/led-components/media/documents/XLampXML.pdf) @ 1A.

I can see voltage on the output, but the LED does not light.

1st PCB was a 2 layer; 2nd PCB was a 4 layer with 2 inner ground layers.

Anyone kindly point out what I might be doing wrong please?

Components used;

[image]

My schematics:
**

- For testing I have only solder the PAM2804 side. For now ignore reset of the circuitry please.
- Direct power injected from a charged Li-ion battery at C1.
- Sorry I have no oscilloscope at the moment. It's on it's way.
  **

[image]

My 2nd PCB:

[image]

Voltages at;

[image]

U1 Pin 1 - 4.092v

U1 Pin 2 - 3.258v **strange this is GND**

U1 Pin 3 - Starts at 3.3v and goes down to 3.089v and stables.

U1 Pin 4 - 4.092v (same as C1 voltage)

U1 Pin 5 - Starts at 3.475v and goes down to 3.369v and stables.

C1 - 4.092v

C7 - Starts at 3.3v and goes down to 3.085v and stables.

Comment: What is the DC voltage on pin 4 of the PAM2804? Is it perhaps too low to get the required 2.98 volts needed for the LED at 1000 mA?

Comment: No component specs. No measurements. No answers.  You need to offer clues of failures.

Comment: "i see voltage" ... voltage is a little vague ... any particular voltage, and how does in compare with the forward voltage of your LED?

Comment: You perhaps have a solder short over small gaps. Record voltage on every pin on schematic

Comment: _"U1 Pin 2 - 3.258v **strange this is GND**"_ - Dry joint on pin 2? Measuring between wrong points? Don't just leave it at that - find out why your 'GND' is not ground!

Comment: All good and working thanks to you! Issue was a silly mistake. i have injected the ground to a wrong rail. My apologies for taking your valuable time. But it helped me to source out my mistake. I've shared my project and it's files on a link in the main post. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I had a pretty similar circuit 2 months ago, using TP4056 with PAM. Since, you are getting the output voltage, only other fault could be coming from lack of current. I would check if

- Amperage and ESR of Inductor L1, are within specified tolerances (0.1 value of R1 will require atleast 1.5amp rated inductor, and LED you are driving requires a minimum of 700mA)
- C1 is MLCC
- C2, C7 could be Tantalum